# Python Arcpy: Non-ASCII character in library import

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I was debugging a basic GIS python script, when I randomly(?) got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 13, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from arcpy.toolbox import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 371, in <module>
    from .management import Graph, GraphTemplate
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 5694
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py on line 5695, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Tried just running `import arcpy` and the same error popped up. So far here's what I tried:

- Ran from Pyscripter and cmd.
- Restarted my computer a couple times.
- Opened that management.py file out of curiosity but it's only a couple hundred lines? I'm a GIS/data analyst, not a programmer of any sort, so this realm is beyond what I know.

I'm stumped. Yes, I could reinstall the library, but that's quite involved as this library is a tiny part of a massive software package.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try add "#encoding: utf-8" in your first row

Comment: Try explaining your solution a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script.

Probably the IDE that you are using, use the default encoding set.